# Memory Issue when trying to plot a TimeSlider map using Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, memory, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to plot an TimeSlider map with Bokeh and I am quite new using those tools. I am working on a Jupyter notebook.

I need give a list of column names of the GeoDataFrame as an argument of the plotting function. The issue is that when I try to add the columns I want in my GeoDataFrame, I can add 6 columns and then my computer crashes (the RAM goes up quasi instantaneously when trying to add the 7th column). I tried to run my notebook in Google Collab, but my session crashes as well when adding a 7th column to my GeoDataFrame. I get no error from Python, and I can't do anything else than reboot my computer.

The plot is correct when I try to implement a Slider with only 6 years, but I'd like to cover 50 years and I'm far from it.

Here is my code:

**Create the GeoDataFrame**

```
df_states = gpd.read_file("countries.geo.json")                    # the GeoDataFrame
frames = {i:dat for i, dat in meat_production.groupby('Year')}     # getting the useful info from another dataset

years = range(1961, 2017)

for y in years:
    frames[y] = frames[y].drop('Year', axis=1)
    df_states = df_states.merge(frames[y], on="id")
    df_states = df_states.rename(columns={'Value': 'Meat %d'%y})
```

The for loop works perfectly for the first iterations and give the result I want.

**Plot the map**

```
slider_columns = ["Meat %d"%i for i in years]

df_states.plot_bokeh(
    figsize = (900,600),
    simplify_shapes=10000,
    slider = slider_columns,
    slider_range = years,
    slider_name = 'Year',
    colormap = 'Inferno',
    hovertool_columns = ['id']+slider_columns,
    title='Meat production'
)
```

Is there another way to define the arguments of plot_bokeh? Do you know how to deal with such issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `plot_bokeh` function is not a part of the actual Bokeh library. Perhaps it is a part of some other, separate, third-party library built on top of Bokeh? In any case I am going to assume that it creates standalone output, not a Bokeh server app. In which case *all the data* is getting sent to the browser, up front. Geo-data especially can explode very quickly. You have not specified any details about the data size, but as a hypothetical example:

```
50 yrs * 100 shapes/yr * 10k pt/shape * 2 coords/pt * 8 bytes/coord ~= 800 MB
```

And that's just to *start*. That's for the original *data-space* coordinates. All those coordinates have to be converted in to screen (i.e. pixel) coordinates which is 2x, so now you are looking at 1.6GB. And still not done. Bokeh is geared towards providing high levels of interactivity, so it puts *all* of that data in a time-efficient spatial index (to support hover, taptools, etc). There's currently no way to opt out of that (tho there is a proposed feature to add a way) and that's another big memory cost that scales quickly with data size. We haven't even mentioned any per-shape or per-vertex attribute data taht might also get sent. But in short you are easily looking at creating on the order of ~3-6GB data *in your browser* with this example. That's just not going to be feasible, things will start to fall over well before this level.

I would say there are a few options:

- Don't send actual shape data. Use something like Datashader and/or GeoViz to pre-render images that can be displayed in Bokeh. This would be a huge reduction in data size in the browser
- Create a Bokeh server application. Then the browser only ever needs to hold *one year of data at a time*. The callback for the slider can be a real Python function that picks out the data for just the single year, and updates the plot to use just that smaller set of data.
- If the shapes don't change year to year then you could also (possibly) just send one copy of the shapes, instead of a copy every year. You could certainly implement that in pure Bokeh code, at least. (Not sure about whatever library built on Bokeh this is)